# Components are not loading while history mode in vue js in laravel

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

When I changed mode to history, the hash from the URL is removed, but components are not loading. This is `app.js`:

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';



var index = Vue.component('index', 
require('./components/frontend/testingIndexComponent.vue'));
var component1 = Vue.component('component1', 
require('./components/frontend/testingComponent.vue'));


Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
mode: 'history',    
routes: [
  { path: '/', component: index },
  { path: '/component1', component: component1 }
]
})
const app = new Vue({
router
}).$mount('#app')
```

this is web.php

```
Route::get('/{vue_capture?}', function () {
return view('index4');
})->where('vue_capture', '[\/\w\.-]*');
```

this is index4.blade.php

```
<body>
  <div>
    <h1>Header</h1>
        <!-- <a><router-link tag="li" to="projects">
            sdds
        </router-link></a> -->
</div>
<div id="app">
    <a><router-link  to="component1">
            sddsdadadssa
        </router-link></a>
    <router-view>

    </router-view>
</div>
<div>
    <h1>Footer</h1>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{URL::to('public/js/app.js')}}"> 
</script>
```

Comment: problem solved. :-)

Comment: can you share the solution please, Thanks

Comment: @MoazzamRafique How?

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
mode: 'history'
```

and use

```
hashbang: false,
history: true
```

instead

Comment: Hi Kelvin and welcome to Stackoverflow. Your contribution is very welcome but would be even better, if you explained in text what your proposed solution actually does or overcomes.